# Can't Edit and Delete posts from my Django post_detail.html template

Tags: python, django, url, django-models, django-views

I've added Edit and Delete buttons to my post_details.html. This is to edit or delete a post added by the owner of the post. It's unfortunate that I'm always running into errors when I access the post_details.html page.

The error is :

**NoReverseMatch at /2020/10/31/django-framework
Reverse for 'post_update' with arguments '(14,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/update$']**

Please I need your help...

Below is the code snippets:

**models.py**

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset(). \
            filter(status='published')


class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='post')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='published')

    objects = models.Manager()  # Default manager
    published = PublishedManager()  # Custom manager
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.month,
                             self.publish.day,
                             self.slug])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'tags', 'status']
    template_name = 'blog/post/post_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(PostUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post/post_confirm_delete.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView


app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # Post views
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/<int:id>/update', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/<int:id>/delete', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% if post.author == user %}
   <div>
     <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-3" 
        href="{% url 'blog:post_update' post.id %}">Edit</a>
     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-3" 
        href="{% url 'blog:post_delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

***Main project url***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
]
```

Comment: There isn't a need to add year, month, and day into the url perameters. The id of the post is unique, so all those values do is complicate your logic, code base, and lengthen the url. I'd suggest that you remove that.

Comment: Alright I'll do that

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I've removed the date and everything is okay now.

Answer (score 1):

```
 {% if post.author == user %}
   <div>
     <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-3" 
        href="{% url 'blog:post_update' post.id %}">Edit</a>
     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-3" 
        href="{% url 'blog:post_delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

**corrected code**

```
{% if post.author == user %}
       <div>
         <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-3" 
            href="{% url 'blog:post_update' post.year post.month post.day post.slug post.id %}">Edit</a>
         <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-3" 
            href="{% url 'blog:post_delete' post.year post.month post.day post.slug post.id %}">Delete</a>
       </div>
    {% endif %}
```

**Pass the appropriate value like year,month,day,slug.... or remove it in your url...**